# Firebase applyActionCode() returns INVALID_OOB_CODE

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to handle email verification in my react client.

So far I managed to send the verification email and the link redirects me to my client where I run `applyActionCode(auth, oobCode)` but I always get `INVALID_OOB_CODE` even though the email is marked as verified.

How do I tell if the oobCode is indeed invalid?

Comment: I had the same problem with react - useEffect because this was rendered twice. The first time the operation was successful, the second time caused the error. So just added this:

`if (auth.currentUser.emailVerified) {
 //code to handle success
}`